# Targeting .NET Core framework

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We have simple application using .NET Core. While running I am getting this error:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.4' was not found.
>   - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>   - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

I have read all related posts but cannot fix the issue.

The browser says:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

I have .NET Core 2.0.2 SDK installed on the server.

My csproj is set to netcoreapp1.0

Apart from downloading/installing version 1.1.2 of .NET Core, is there any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: Why don't u run it as netcoreapp2.0?

Comment: .NET Core 1.x is dying quickly, so upgrading to 2.x should be your priority right now.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are on Windows Server trying to host aspnetcore apps. Have you installed? [ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your .csproj file and update version to 1.0.4 (or the version you're currently using). Make sure it's uniform elsewhere and attempt to reproduce.